# Getting current Git commit version from within Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I retrieve the current Git commit version from within a Ruby on Rails app?

Want to display the Git version (or maybe the last 6 letters or so) to serve as an App version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can invoke the `git` command from within your script:

```
commit = `git show --pretty=%H`
puts commit
```

Depending on your environment you may want to use the full path to the git binary, and possibly specify the GIT_DIR via an environment variable or `--git-dir`.

Comment: Learned something new today, thanks! Didn't know you could use back-quotes for shell commands.

Comment: I haven't used it so I can't recommend it from experience but you can use [grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit) if you want something that's more OO.

Comment: Aaron, considered grit, but that's a more involved solution than my simple use.

Answer (score 22):

Like @meagar said, use backticks to execute the shell command from within your app, but you may find these two commands more useful:

Full hash:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

First 7 characters of hash:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

Comment: I used `commit = \`git rev-parse HEAD\`.chomp` to remove the trailing newline

Comment: So, in Rails console: `puts \`git rev-parse HEAD\``

Answer (score 5):

A more robust solution would be `git show --pretty=%H -q`. The [`-q` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref#git-show-ref--q) quiets the output.

In order to remove the newline that is part of the output, you can use chomp. For example: `system('git show --pretty=%H -q').chomp`

The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407126/getting-current-git-commit-version-from-within-rails-app#answer-8407170) has the potential to actually return the diff when the commit is *not* a merge commit. Verified on git version 2.16.2.windows.1.

Comment: Amazing. I asked this question 7 yrs ago, and was just utilizing the answers again in a Heroku app, and you actually posted an answer at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you want to include the app version in your HTML somewhere? The prerequisite is that you are deploying your repo with Capistrano in the default manner (you are uploading the repo, not sending up an archive file).

You can add some code to the Rails initializer as [outlined here](http://blog.andrewvc.com/making-life-easier-with-git-shas-in-your-http). That approach will get the SHA1 from the last commit, and make it available as an environment variable.

The other way to do it is have you Capistrano task generate a static file in the public directory with the commit SHA in it. You could include other info in this file that seems useful.

Comment: With capistrano 3, simply read the file REVISION, in current folder.